# How to conver NODE to STAGE in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I need to run commands over server using SSH.
I found this [https://github.com/jenkinsci/ssh-steps-plugin][plugin] that does it nicely.
but it's written as a node, and not as pipeline step.

```
node {
  def remote = [:]
  remote.name = 'test'
  remote.host = 'test.domain.com'
  remote.user = 'root'
  remote.password = 'password'
  remote.allowAnyHosts = true
  stage('Remote SSH') {
    sshRemove remote: remote, path: "abc.sh"
  }
}
```

How can I transform it to `pipeline {}` stage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is straight forward you can simply move above remote steps into stage. I used to do like below. (I have used private key for ssh authentication)

```
steps {
        script {
            def remote = [:]
            withCredentials([
                sshUserPrivateKey(credentialsId: 'PRIVATE_KEY_FILE', keyFileVariable: 'identityFile', passphraseVariable: 'passphrase', usernameVariable: 'userName')
            ]) {
            remote.name = "test.host.com"
            remote.host = "10.0.0.1"
            remote.allowAnyHosts = true
            remote.user = userName
            remote.identityFile = identityFile
            remote.passphrase = passphrase
            sshScript remote: remote, script: "runTestScript.sh"
        }
    }
}
```

Please refer https://github.com/jenkinsci/ssh-steps-plugin#pipeline-steps

Comment: I'm getting an exception:
```org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:

WorkflowScript: 22: Expected a when condition @ line 22, column 21.

                       def remote = [:]```

Comment: Can you please share me the entire jenkinsfile here.

Comment: Here is the full working Jenkinsfile snippet:                                                       
 pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage ("SSH Connect"){
            steps {
                script {
                    def remote = [:]
                    remote.name = "testServer.com"
                 remote.host = "10.1.1.1"
              remote.allowAnyHosts = true
              remote.user = "userName"
              remote.password = "password"
                sshScript remote: remote, script: "runTestScript.sh"
             }
         }
        }
    }
}